# How to render a Widget just a single time, independent of external requests?

Tags: html, haskell, yesod, monad-transformers

Yesod makes it very simple to have web pages (built up from `Widget`s) rendered to HTML whenever they are requested externally through `warp`'s port. Why, that is of course precisely where we *usually* need the HTML.

But what if I also need a copy of that HTML for “internal purposes”, generated independently of the usual `Handler` setting? You'd think that `Widget` is essentially just a reader/writer combination, reading a `Yesod` and writing a tuple of HTML, CSS and JS results. [The documentation itself](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-core-1.4.32/docs/Yesod-Core-Widget.html#t:WidgetT) says “...this is simply a `WriterT`...”. Ok, but...

```
newtype WidgetT site m a = WidgetT
    { unWidgetT :: HandlerData site (MonadRoute m) -> m (a, GWData (Route site))
    }
```

handlerdatasiteroutegwdataroute... ugh.

*How do I invoke this and get at the result HTML that would normally just be sent straight to the client*, without actually embedding the widget in any `Handler`?

So, I basically want

```
runWidget :: Widget -> MyYesod -> IO Html
```

i.e.

```
             WidgetT MyYesod IO () -> MyYesod -> IO Html
```

Am I just missing some function that does this, or is there a problem – perhaps widgets are actually more powerful than I thought? If so, what would be the correct type to express just *`Writer` of HTML and CSS together*?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect, you can turn `Widget` into `Handler` using `defaultLayout` or even `widgetToPageContent` and `withUrlRenderer` first, and then "run" it with this tiny helper:

```
handler :: Handler a -> IO a
handler h = getAppSettings >>= makeFoundation >>= flip unsafeHandler h
```

You can also use `handler . runDB` to "run" DB actions this way.

Comment: `do {html <- defaultLayout widget; sendByEmail recipient html}`